# How to do this simple interface in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

First, I'm sure this question has already been asked but I'm also sure I do not know what to type on Google or SO to find the answer. So, I ask it.

I want an interface with one key called `id` which is of type `number`. There can be others keys that we do not know the name and have string values.

I tried this:

```
export interface MyInterface {
  id: number
  [key: string]: string
}
```

but it is telling me

> Property 'id' of type 'number' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.

Is there a way to achieve that ?

Comment: Why don't you declare an object like `other_key {key: string, value: string}`

Comment: @tobias I don't want to change the structure of my object

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I found this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10042

and in documentations about indexable types

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types

says

> **they also enforce that all properties match their return type.**

So probably your behavior can't be resolved!

---

Hope this solution is ok for you:

```
export interface MyInterface {
    id: number;
    [key: string]: string | number;
}
```

And the type-safe for `id` works.

[image]

Comment: This would work but would also allow `someProp` to be a `number` which I do not want :)